# React.js + node.js on azure

Tags: node.js, azure, reactjs, deployment

I'm trying to make a React.js app working on NodeJs in an Azure Web App. 
The app works fine locally but in Azure it is returning the same content for all the files.

The app has 3 main files:

- index.html (this file references the other two)
- bundle.js
- styles.css

Locally when opening the app in the browser, index.html is served togheter with the other 2 files. Each of them has the correct content.

On Azure, instead, bundle.js and styles.css have the content of index.html

The node app has this relevant configuration:

```
app.use(express.static('dist'));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
});
```

The web.config file on azure is the normal one generated by the app. I played with it but didn't manage to go around the problem.

The way I understand it is that web.config realizes that bundle.js and styless.css are public files and should send the proper request to node witch should serve them via the static set up above. 
The index.html is served for any URL so that refreshing the page actually works.

Could you please tell me what I'm missing here?

Here is also the relevant part of the web.config file:

```
<handlers>
  <!-- Indicates that the server.js file is a node.js site to be handled by the iisnode module -->
  <add name="iisnode" path="bin/app.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode"/>
</handlers>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <!-- Do not interfere with requests for node-inspector debugging -->
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^bin/app.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>

    <!-- First we consider whether the incoming URL matches a physical file in the /public folder -->
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="dist{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>

    <!-- All other URLs are mapped to the node.js site entry point -->
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="bin/app.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I removed the bin folder as a last thing to try tonight. It worked!

The problem was probably the "/" character in the regex (bin/app.js) ... :(